# Experiment 3: Capacitors in series and parallel circuits

Tags: electrostatics, capacitance

Can someone please explain me the theory that explain that the total capacitance in a parallel circuit is the total of the individual capacitance of each capacitor added together.

Comment: If you take a capacitor, cut it in half, and ensure that each half is connected to the battery with the same polarity that it had before you cut it in half, how much capacitance do you have?

Answer (score 0):

this is easy to understand:

Draw a capacitor on a piece of paper as a little pair of parallel plates oriented horizontally, with a little wire coming out of the center of each pointing straight up and straight down.

Right next to it and very close, draw a second capacitor in exactly the same way so the parallel plates of the first almost touch those of the second. It will look like this:

```
       |           |   here are the wires
       |           |
  _____|_____ _____|_____     
  ___________ ___________      these are the plates
       |           |
       |           |
       |           |    here are the wires
```

Each capacitor has capacitance C. Now draw a short little line joining the upper pair of plates together and the lower pair of plates together, so you now have just *one* pair of plates, twice as big as the two individual pairs of plates. It will look like this:

```
       |           |   here are the wires
       |           |
  _____|___________|_____     
  _______________________      these are the plates, now joined together
       |           |
       |           |
       |           |    here are the wires
```

when the plates are joined together, the resulting capacitor is twice as big, and its capacitance is now 2C!

This is why *parallel capacitances* add together in a circuit.